# Combination of find command and sed (stream editor)

Tags: shell-script, files, find

I am trying to find all directories in /proc with names containing only numbers and belonging to users other than "root"

I have already tried this:

```
sudo find /proc -type d -user | sed -n '/[0-9]/p'
```

But it doesn't work in appropriate way at all.
I'll apply any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me...

```
find /proc -type d ! -user root ! -name '*[!0-9]*'
```

That's a pretty handy search to run, actually. Thank you.

You might want to tack a `2>/dev/null` on the end, though. `find` complains a *lot* about `/proc` for me.

Comment: Somehow but it doesn't work completely for me. о_О Two directories of mine are not included in. These directories are not under "root".

Comment: @Nitro84 - only 2? Are you completely sure those directories actually exist when you run the command? `/proc` is confusing like that - because new processes must needs pop up all of the time - and especially if you're running some other command to verify the output of this one - then you'll likely wind up finding all kinds of discrepancies. It's all very temporary. That said, maybe the command is sh*t, but I can't think what it would miss.

Comment: I found out that when I used just "ls" command to compare with the result of your command - all directories were included. But when I used "ls-l" there were another two directories that were not under root.

Comment: @Nitro84 - those are likely the process directories associated with the `ls` process - and if you're doing anything with a pipe `|` the shell will spawn a subshell. And so each time you run a new command, you'll get new process directories associated with your username, and those won't have existed at the time you ran `find` in the first place. That's what I meant before - it's very temporary. I think if you look harder you'll also notice that at least *one* directory which *was* there when you ran `find` is no longer there when you scan with `ls` because `find` isn't running any more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation!There is a lot to take in for me! Linux has a lot  of hidden obstacles as for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
find /proc -type d ! -user 'root' -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/[0-9]+" -ls
```

To go further, check

```
man 1 find
```